# D: undesired anonymous function attributes

Tags: lambda, d

Consider the following template:

```
mixin template test(void function() callback)
{
    static this()
    {
        callback();
    }
}
```

This works:

```
mixin test!(&sort_arr);
void sort_arr()
{
    arr.sort;
}
```

However this doesn't work:

```
mixin test!({ arr.sort; });
```

DMD gives the following error:

```
Error: safe function 'main.__lambda6' cannot call system function '_adSort'
Error: @nogc function 'main.__lambda6' cannot call non-@nogc function '_adSort'
```

It seems to me that the lambda version is inferred to be `safe @nogc`, while the explicit `sort_arr` isn't.

How can I overcome this and pass an anonymous lambda to this template?

---

**Edit:** bug report filed as per the recommendation in the accepted answer: https://issues.dlang.org/show_bug.cgi?id=13481

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a bug with inferring attributes from built-in properties. You can report it at D's issue tracker, at http://issues.dlang.org/.

However, note that the built-in `.sort` property/function is on its way to being deprecated. Please use `std.algorithm.sort` instead, which shouldn't have this issue.

Comment: I was aiming for `std.algorithm.sort`, I didn't realize there is a built-in one...

Comment: To clarify, you need to import `std.algorithm` and do `arr.sort()` instead of `arr.sort`. This is for historical reasons and will not be necessary eventually once the built-in sort is properly removed.